# transferring a property into an event function within an objects method

Tags: javascript, events, properties

I am trying to take an objects property and transfer it into a keypress event - trouble is you can only add the event itself and using this.x_point will not work in a child function. here is my code. i could also tranfer this.x_point to var.x_point and then use it but that ruins the point of it being an object at all.

```
function ninja(name, speed){
this.name = name;
this.speed = speed;
this.x_point = 0;
this.y_point = 0;
loadImages("n_main", 0, 0);
loadImages("n_armL", -5, 8);
loadImages("n_armR", 25, 8);
```

}

```
ninja.prototype.move = function(){
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress, false);
function keyPress(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 68){ //d
        alert(this.x_point);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bind for this:

```
ninja.prototype.move = function(){
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress.bind(this), false);
function keyPress(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 68){ //d
        alert(this.x_point);
    }
}
```

Or if you use jQuery try jQuery.proxy(keyPress, this).

Comment: thanks, the perfect fix, I never thought of this as a stand alone thing

Answer (score 0):

If you use `that` for example:

```
ninja.prototype.move = function(){
 var that = this;
 window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress, false);
 function keyPress(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 68){ //d
    alert(that.x_point);
 }
}
```

Comment: If you can select an answer it would be perfect so that it doesn't appear anymore in the unanswered section of the site